# General Solution to Linear Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

I am trying to find a solution to
$$\displaystyle \left[-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 - \frac{2}{r} + C(r)\right]\phi(r) = E\phi(r)$$
where $C(r)$ is a known function of r. I am just looking for some help on the strategy to solve explicitly for $\phi(r)$. I have read through the solution for hydrogen using separation of variables but

1) I don't really understand it, they make a lot of handwavy arguments about terms disappearing  :)

2) How does one handle the extra $C(r)$?

FYI: this is for the Hartree Fock method on Helium so the actual equation is the one posted in the answer here: [Hartree Fock equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168042/hartree-fock-equations)

P.S. I posted this in math.stackechange first should I close that one?

Comment: Do you have mathematica?

Comment: Haha no I don't :( but can Mathematica handle it? Also I am trying to implement my own HF algorithm in Python so if I could come up with an analytical solution that would be awesome.

Comment: There's no general algorithm that can provide solutions for a generic $C(r)$. If only it were that simple! Wolfram Alpha's 'DSolve' can provide solace for some simple $C(r)$ but will quickly run out of computing steam for more complicated $C(r)$.

Comment: @user2879934: HF-based methods provide numerical solutions, not analytical ones.

Comment: @Gert well kind of this is just one step in HF for helium...we have already turned it into a one body problem that should be solvable by integrating out the effect of the second electron and turned it into an effective field. The step in HF that I am stuck on is I guessed my orbitals as Guassian and I calculated C(r) but how the heck to I generate a new psi using the Hamiltonian? Sorry for typos on phone

Comment: @user2879934: hmmm... why do you think for $\mathrm{He}$ we use perturbation theory? What's the form of your $C(r)$ anyway? I'm afraid you're chasing a pipe dream, TBH...

Comment: So C(r) is just the integral of my guess of the psi function times its complex conjugate divided by the r12 operator. So, it only depends on r1 luckily since r2 gets integrated out. But what I don't get is how do people actually do HF? All the textbooks get to the self contained field theory and say hey look we have a one electron Hamiltonian that looks like hydrogen now solve it to get an improved psi. But that's what I'm trying to do here, so if it is really difficult is HF just a theoretical thing?

Comment: @user2879934: not, it's not a 'theoretical thing' at all: tons of software is based on it (and other methods), see e.g.https://orcaforum.cec.mpg.de/. I'm bookmarking this question to see other comments/answers. Good night and good luck!

Comment: Do you assume that $\phi(r)$ depends only on the radial coordinate (i.e. $L=0$)? Usually the only reason you would write $V(r)=-2/r+C(r)$ is if you are doing perturbation theory in $C(r)$ (or if $C(r)$ includes the effect of angular momentum). Also, Hartree Fock theory can be thought of as a variational approach to approximating energy spectra. In HF theory, the space of wavefunctions over which $\langle \psi|H|\psi\rangle$ is extremized is either the set of all `Slater determinants', or sums of (say) at most $k$ Slater determinants.

Comment: For $C(r)=0$, Mathematica found $\phi(r) \sim e^{-r} (M(\dots r) + {}_1 F_1 (\dots r))$ where $M$ is a confluent hypergeometric. I've tried experimenting with different $C(r)$ and Mathematica has not been able to find closed-form solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do Hartree-Fock to Helium atom, you just need to calculate one orbital, which for helium is spherically symmetric. The Hartree-Fock 'integro-differential' equation for spherically symmetric atom with one eigenstate can be written as

$$\left(-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 - \frac{2}{r} + V_{Hx}(r) \right) u(r) = \epsilon u(r),$$

where $u(r) = \psi(r) r$ and

$$V_{Hx}(r) = \frac{1}{2} \int d{\bf r}' \frac{n({\bf r'})}{|{\bf r-r}'|}$$
The factor $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from exchange term cancelling half of the Hartree-potential.

I would recommend shooting method. (Alternatives: gaussian basis set, finite element, finite difference methods).

Shooting method is simple. Guess an eigenvalue and integrate the solution of radial Schrödinger equation from r=0 to r=r_max. Require that boundary condition is fulfilled at r_max (zero). If not, change the eigenvalue accordingly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method

Solving the radial Hartree-Fock potential equation is also super simple.

$$ \int dr' \frac{n(r')}{|r-r'|} = \frac{1}{r} \int_0^r dr' 4\pi n(r) r^2 + \int_r^\infty 4\pi n(r) r $$

(Eq. 7.6 here) https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/_static/rostgaard_master.pdf

The latter part of my answer here explains how this equation works.
[Dipole in a spherical cavity in an infinite dielectric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218599/dipole-in-a-spherical-cavity-in-an-infinite-dielectric/219537#219537)

Beware, that the Fock-operator is only multiplicative for the Helium 1s orbitals. Rest of the eigenvalue spectrum of the given equation does not match to Fock-operator spectrum.

edit: I just read a comment of yours, which stated that you are using gaussian orbitals. You can solve it easily. You just need to calculate some matrix elements. Given a set of gaussian orbitals $\phi_i$, you calculate two matrices

$$H_{ij} = < \phi_i | H | \phi_j>$$

and

$$S_{ij} = < \phi_i | \phi_j >$$.

Then you solve this generalized eigenvalue equation

$$Hc=\epsilon Sc$$,
and you get the new coefficients for the wave function as the eigenvector. Your wave function is now

$$ \psi(r) = \sum_n c_n \phi_n(r) $$

The method is called subspace diagonalization.

To solve the generalized eigenvalue equation with octave or Matlab,

```
octave:1> H = [ -2 0.1 ; 0.1 -3 ];
octave:2> S = [ 1 0.1 ; 0.1 1 ];
octave:5> [psi, lambda] = eig(H,S)
psi =

  -0.35088  -0.94180
   0.97217  -0.25494

lambda =

Diagonal Matrix

  -3.1498        0
        0  -1.9209
```

Here you obtain the eigenvalues (-3.14 is the lowest), and the corresponding eigenvector [-0.35, 0.97]. Now, all that there is left, is to fill matrices H and S with the real matrix elements.

To be more spesific, following integrals must be evaluated:

$$H_{ij} = \int dr \phi_i(r) (-1/2 \nabla^2 + V(r) ) \phi_j(r) \\
S_{ij} =  \int dr \phi_i(r) \phi_j(r) $$

Comment: In $$Hc=\epsilon Sc$$ are you solving for $\epsilon$ to update the coefficient? Also how does one solve that? Thanks so much Mikael!

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly. One doesn't update epsilon, but obtains directly the correct value. This is called direct diagonalization. For large problems, one uses iterative diagonalization where $\epsilon$ is estimated and converged iteratively.

Comment: oh man! I didn't realize math packages had the ability to solve eigien-value equations. That is awesome thank you!

Comment: Actually one last thing...what "does fill matrices H and S with the real matrix elements" mean? Sorry I am just  a computer programmer :)

Comment: Haven't we already filled them by evaluating the two given integrals?

Comment: I editted the answer to contain the integrals you need to evaluate. For spherical symmetry it is easy to do them oneself. There are libraries to di general integrals with gaussian functions for more advanged stuff.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I was just confused by the wording, by fill in the matrices you meant just evaluate the integrals :)

Comment: Sorry I have so many questions: by dr do you mean literally just with respect to radius, or do you mean an implicit triple integral in spherical coordinates? I guess it doesn't matter since adding phi and theta just adds a constant multiple but what about that gradient term in there is that just d^2/dr^2?

Comment: You need to do angles as well. If the integral is spherical symmetric, the angle integrals can be done trivially and 4pi r*2 is left. Look what is laplacian in spherical coordinates. If it is too scary, you can do a partial integration, and with gradients it will be easier.

Comment: https://rsc.anu.edu.au/~pgill/papers/045Review.pdf here is how to calculate integrals. Yet another trick for kinetic energy presented there.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this question is a little too open ended and I'm sorry for that...but I did find a WONDERFUL HF walk through http://www.phys.sinica.edu.tw/TIGP-NANO/Course/2011_Spring/classnotes/CMS_20110511.pdf that clears everything up.